# how do i modify a button back to the default button format in java?

Tags: android, button

Normally the buttons have this nice looking formatting.  For most of my program i want to change my button background to an invisible background, and i use

```
myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

so i can still see the text but not the background.  then later on i do

```
 myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREY);
```

but my button just looks like a grey textbox with text, it loses all its nice button formatting.  how can i change it back to have the nice default button feel?  am i making the background invisible incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could save the drawable of the button and set it back to how it was later:

```
    Drawable originalBackground = button.getBackground();

    button.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    ...
    button.setBackgroundDrawable(originalBackground);
```

Answer (score 2):

myButton.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
Will set it to the default.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be 9-patch drawables, which you can use to completely customize your buttons very easily (and they look great, because they are not stretched!) 
For details see http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html